# count frequency based on values in 2 or more columns

Tags: r, count, frequency, multiple-columns

I have a pretty simple question but I can't think of a way to do this without using if statements

The data I have looks something like:

```
df <- structure(list(years = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), x = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("E", "I"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("years", 
"id", "x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

so the table looks like:

```
   years id x
1      1  1 I
2      2  1 E
3      3  1 E
4      1  1 E
5      2  1 I
6      3  1 I
7      1  2 I
8      2  2 E
9      3  2 I
10     1  2 E
11     2  2 E
12     3  2 I
13     1  3 I
14     2  3 E
15     3  3 I
16     1  3 I
17     2  3 I
18     3  3 E
```

I would like the output to report the fraction of x's that are "I" for each id and each year:

```
   years id xnew
1      1  1 0.5
2      2  1 0.5
3      3  1 0.5
4      1  2 0.5
5      2  2 0.0
6      3  2 1.0
7      1  3 1.0
8      2  3 0.5
9      3  3 0.5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: sorry that wasn't clear, i've editted my question to include the df table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggregate(x ~ years + id, data=df, function(y) sum(y=="I")/length(y) )

  years id   x
1     1  1 0.5
2     2  1 0.5
3     3  1 0.5
4     1  2 0.5
5     2  2 0.0
6     3  2 1.0
7     1  3 1.0
8     2  3 0.5
9     3  3 0.5
```

Comment: @user2303635 - if this worked it is customary to tick the green arrow next to the answer so others know it is an appropriate solution. Glad it helped.